# Isotope second row downwards moves left and right on mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, jquery-isotope

I'm making a webshop and used [this guide](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/06/16/filterable-product-grid/) as a start.

I'm building the webshop in MVC and it seems to work perfect on any browser, but as soon as I run the website on a mobile(Tested iphone 6) the second row move left and right when your scroll down.

I have uploaded a screenshop from my Phone:

On page load: [image]

When I scroll down or up this happens: [image]

Do anyone have an idea why this happens?

You can try it yourself at [www.Webshop.loevbo.com](http://www.Webshop.loevbo.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the error. I have in some way got hold on an older version of isotope. After a quick version check, I updated the file and now it works as it shall.